# chrome.storage.sync failed to SET and GET

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am unable to save and get data when I put any data and click button nothing happen and not saving data.

Just want to save 2 value

1. APIkey
2. enabled or not a checkbox

and save them

My main.js for options

```
function saveSettings(e) {
chrome.storage.sync.set({
    apiKey: apiKey.value,
    isEnabled: isEnabled.checked

});
}

function restoreSettings(e) {
chrome.storage.sync.get("apiKey").then(
    function(result) {
        alert('working');
        apiKey.value = result.apiKey || "";
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
chrome.storage.sync.get("isEnabled").then(
    function(result) {
        isEnabled.checked = result.isEnabled
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
}



//restoreSettings();
//saveButton.addEventListener("click", saveSettings);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restoreSettings);
document.getElementById('saveButton').addEventListener('click',
saveSettings);
```

And my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Plugin Options</title>

</head>
<body>

<img src="/icons/img1.png">

<div>

<form style="background-color:#000a1a">


    <h3>Change Settings</h3>
    <label>API Key : <input type="text" id="apiKey" /></label><br />
    <label>Enabled : <input type="checkbox" id="isEnabled" /></label><br />
    <input type="button" value="Save Settings" id="saveButton" class="button" />


</form>
</div>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried `chrome.storage.local` as well thanks for helping

Comment: Chrome API does not support Promises. It's callback-based. See the documentation. A common workaround is to use the Mozilla's WebExtension polyfill.

Comment: I feel this comment should be an answer (a bit more detailed perhaps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have set the right permissions in your manifest:

```
"permissions": [
        "storage"
    ]
```

then to get a value:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('myvalue', function(res){
})
```

where `res.myvalue` will be the content you are looking for.

To set a value do:

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({'myvalue': true})
```